# Tootip não funciona no flutter

Tags: flutter, tooltip

Estou seguindo esse tutorial [clique aqui](https://www.tutorialkart.com/flutter/flutter-tooltip/).

E o tooltip não apareceu. Será que está faltando alguma coisa no meu código logo abaixo?

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Nomeação de lideres"),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[900],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Tooltip(
                  message: 'My Account',
                  child: FlatButton(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.access_time,
                      size: 100,
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ]),
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Resultado da minha tela;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É porque o seu botão não está com o método de click implementado...

Experimente implementar o `onPressed(){}`

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Nomeação de lideres"),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[900],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Tooltip(
                  message: 'My Account',
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Faltou isso aqui
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.access_time,
                      size: 100,
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ]),
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Obs.: Lembrando que hoje nas versões atuais o *FlatButton* foi substituído por *TextButton* ou *ElevatedButton*.*